# hibernate generatation: different alias from same query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, hibernate-mapping

We have noticed (Hibernate 3.6.3 Final) that same query in our logs generates different SQL sentences (inner joins).

Is there any reason that this behavior is not deterministic?

In our own research we have found that aliases are generated this way (org.hibernate.mapping.Column) , we do not have find out the clue that makes this algorith vary between two same inputs...

```
public String getAlias(Dialect dialect) {
    String alias = name;
    String unique = Integer.toString(uniqueInteger) + '_';
    int lastLetter = StringHelper.lastIndexOfLetter(name);
    if ( lastLetter == -1 ) {
        alias = "column";
    }
    else if ( lastLetter < name.length()-1 ) {
        alias = name.substring(0, lastLetter+1);
    }
    if ( alias.length() > dialect.getMaxAliasLength() ) {
        alias = alias.substring( 0, dialect.getMaxAliasLength() - unique.length() );
    }
    boolean useRawName = name.equals(alias) && 
        !quoted && 
        !name.toLowerCase().equals("rowid");
    if ( useRawName ) {
        return alias;
    }
    else {
        return alias + unique;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you migrate away from this 11 year old version to currents versions like 5.6 or 6.1, then someone in the community might be able to help you with that, but since that version is not maintained anymore, you are most likely on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Probable cause is a bug in Hibertante that wasn't fixed until 4.1.10 version: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2448